# Is there a German equivalent to the saying "to be in love with the sound of one's own voice"?

Tags: idiom

I'm in a meeting where somebody is talking too much and was wondering how can I talk about this guy with my colleagues afterwards. Does German have a way of saying "he's really in love with the sound of his own voice?"

Comment: I think it would help with a question like this to provide an explanation of the specific meaning of the idiom. (Keep in mind that many of the regulars here are not native English speakers.) I'd say the expression is used to describe a self-centered person who is constantly talking, usually about things that no one cares about, and who isn't interested in what other people have to say.

Comment: The literal translation ("der mag [einfach, wirklich] den Klang seiner eigenen Stimme") would also be perfectly intelligible in context, even though it is not a common idiom.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Please do not use the comment function to post answers. See https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Yeah, I know. It didn't seem a complete answer somehow (it is not an equivalent because it is not idiomatic) -- and in a way it obviates the question, doesn't it?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: If you can't provide a complete answer, please don't publish incomplete fragments anywhere. If you feel unsure about the purpose of comments, please get informed here: https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Thank you for informing me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is the standard phrase

> ... sich selbst gerne reden hören

(literally meaning *to like to listen to oneself talking*) which is quite close.

Your sentence then would read

> Er hört sich selbst gerne reden.

Comment: @infinitezero Good idea to add the literal translation! However, I would rather translate it as _to like to hear oneself talk_ (_to like to listen to oneself talking_ would be more "sich selbst gern zuhören")

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I would expect "gerne" to be a quite bit less than "love".  Is that correct?

Comment: "gerne" vs. "love": understatement is the name of the game here. You can do *a lot* with the tone in which this is said.

Comment: [...] Plus the non-verbal accompaniment. ;-)    Also: my preference would be to use "zuhören" on this occasion as it's more, äh, *attentive* (focused?) than simply "hören" (or "reden hören", which to my ears doesn't have the *Schwung* of "zuhören": "reden hören" doesn't roll off the tongue just as smoothly in comparison, but that's very fine detail and, I expect, a matter of taste (like your favorite literature or actors).

Comment: @GerHobbelt that’s missing the point. Someone who “likes to listen to oneself” is actually someone who likes to talk (a lot) without listening to anyone. So “hören” is more appropriate than “zuhören”, as the latter implies a commitment that contradicts the problem of that person. Compare with the response “Hörst Du Dir eigentlich manchmal selbst zu?” a question that implies if the person would actually listen (“zuhören”), they would start noticing the problems of their talking.

Comment: @Holger: you're correct, of course: *hören* sticks closest (literal translation). To me, the remark is sarcastic by default and *zuhören* adds extra punch that way, making it "tastier" to my ears. A bit like "rubbing it in" there and then: after all, you only would make the remark if you already know they don't "listen". :-)